# Python Error : the truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, logical-operators

I want to compare item in list, this is my code:

```
for i in range(200):
        if g[i]==1 and d[4]==1:
           TP += 1
        elif g[i]==1 and d[4]==0:
           FP += 1
        elif g[i]==0 and d[4]==1:
           FN += 1
        elif g[i]==0 and d[4]==0:
           TN += 1
```

and I got this Error :

> the truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.
>   use a.any() or a.all()

I don't know how to use the syntax as recommended above, how to solve it, thanks.

Comment: What is the type of `g`? Of `d`?

Comment: g is an array of integer, a list. d is array too.

Comment: Solved it, actually it's not logical operator error, I forget that d is 2 dimensional array

Comment: 2 dimensional array? does python have array? are you using external module?

Comment: 'd' is 2d array, but I was accessing it like 1d array(look at code above), that's the problem, solved now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by the author in comments, `d` is a 2-dimensional Numpy array.

The answer to [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous#10063039) question explains that comparing multidimensional arrays in Numpy requires to the kind of comparison you want to perform (either any element is bitwise true or all elements are bitwise true).
That is the reason why you have to specify which kind of comparison you want, with `(g[i] - d[4]).any()` or `(g[i] - d[4]).all()`.

Comment: solved it, actually it's not logical operator error, but I was accessing 2d array like 1d array, soved.